# Whatsapp not sending or receiving messages with one particular number

Tags: whatsapp

I have discovered whatsapp recently. It works fine for me in general, but for a particular friend, she is not receiving my messages, and I am not receiving her messages. Both telephone numbers are correct, and both of us able to use whatsapp with others.

Any idea ? Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Do you see one check mark on the messages sent to her? Or do you see a clock like symbol?

Comment: Any chance one of you have blocked the other?

Comment: I am also facing same issue.
And we are receiving messages from other whatsapp accounts. Neither of us is blocked.
I get a single tick and my friend gets a clock like symbol.
And this happens only for our accounts.
Rest all is fine. This happens intermittently and somehow the messages get delivered later in the day..but with too much delay